# Auto-activation of the conda environment in the terminal (ps, cmd, bash) in VS Code on Windows 11 does not work. How to solve this problem?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, anaconda

I work in VS Code in Python and use conda environments.
Previously, the environment, after selecting it as a python interpreter, was automatically activated in the terminal. Currently, auto-activation does not occur for locally created workspace environments. It is still activated when you run the python script, but there is no clear indication in the terminal that the environment is currently activated. Checked with the `python' command in the terminal - it indicates the python version of the base environment, not the user's local one.
My configuration:

- Windows 11 Pro 23H2
- Motherboard: Gigabyte Aorus Elite AX Z590
- CPU: i7 11700k
- Visual Studio Code v.1.87.2
- miniconda3 v.24.3.0
- python 3.11.8 - 3.12
- python extension for VS Code v.2024.2.1

What's checked:

- conda in the path variable - yes
- conda in the Windows terminal (ps, cmd) - yes
- PS in execution policy - yes

What is done:

- Clean reinstallation of Windows 11 and all its components
- Clean reinstallation of miniconda3, made sure that all paths are registered in path, works from under any Windows terminal.
- Clean reinstallation of VSCode without syncing user settings
- Reinstalled all python extensions for VSCode
- Prescribed conda init for all shells

Interesting notes:

- If the local anonymous environment was created in 2023, then auto-activation works on Windows 11
- If you work on Windows 10, then auto-activation works with any environment
- Windows 11 auto-activates all named global environments
- An attempt to create an environment in Windows 10 and transfer it to a project on Windows 11 failed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use a very similar setup: Windows 11, VS Code, Conda environments. This does not appear as an issue for me.  However, when I open the terminal, a pop up message appears in the bottom right corner:

[image]

The "Learn more" link points to a wiki page on the VSCode-Python github page:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Activate-Environments-in-Terminal-Using-Environment-Variables

Comment: Yes, I saw this message. And the right environment is actually activated. But the problem is that every time I change the environment (for example, adding a new package), I need to activate it explicitly. At the same time, problems with the PyQt5 package also occur (the JPEG file is not readable in QPixmap). But it can only be read when the environment is clearly activated(

Comment: New environments created in 2024 will not auto-activate. And the old ones (until 2024) are activated automatically successfully

Comment: How are you creating the new environments?  From the Anaconda/Conda prompt, of from within VS Code?

Comment: from vs code. ctrl+shift+p -> create environment ->conda->python 3.12.